# show a text from a jquery condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make the the div spt-wrap load one of 2 conditions time when hasClass status on or off

Regards

Comment: There's no such thing as a "jQuery condition". Please include the relevant code here on Stack Overflow. Use Stack Snippets (icon looks like `<>` in the toolbar) for a very jsFiddle-like UI.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours

Comment: Hello @RachelGallen I apologize, i tried to edit but i'm getting a message alert that i put many codes  ; Sorry again

Comment: @AbdelmoulaNami What exact conditions do you want to check for? Your description of the problem is that you want to check whether it's between 8 am and 9 pm, but your code seems to be checking for all sorts of other conditions like day of the week. You're also making it really difficult for yourself by converting the 24-hour time format to 12-hour format, which then requires you to check whether it's am/pm. Why not just pass in the hours in 24-hour format to make things easy?

Comment: Hello @kmoser, I need please a script that shows a message (we are on line) when it's GMT+1 between 08 and 17:00, and message (we are offline) for other hours , thank you

Comment: @AbdelmoulaNami That is not what was requested in your question. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66860344/edit) to reflect the exact times you want to display when you are online and when you are offline.

Comment: Hello @Kmoser , I can't edit or update my post , I'm getting this message "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."

Comment: Hi @RachelGallen how can I close this topic please

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        ;(function(element){
            var $element = $(element), $wrap = $('.spt-wrap', $element);
            var smart_today = new Date('Sat Apr 03 2021 04:20:11 ') ;
            function getdate($timezone){
                var guest_today = new Date();
                var today = ($timezone == 'current_timezone')? smart_today : guest_today;
                if($timezone == 'current_timezone'){
                    // today.setMinutes(today.getMinutes());
                    // today.setHours(today.getHours());
                    today.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 1 );
                    today.setSeconds(guest_today.getSeconds());
                }
                
                var ap = '';
                var h = today.getHours();
                var m = today.getMinutes();         
                var s = today.getSeconds();
                
                var $time = [];     
                $time[0] = ap = ( h < 12 ) ? 'AM' : 'PM';
                $time[1] = h  = ( h <= 12 ) ? h : h - 12;
                $time[1] = h  = ( h < 10 ) ? '0'+ h : h;
                $time[2] = m  = ( m < 10 ) ? '0'+ m : m;
                $time[3] = s  = ( s < 10 ) ? '0'+ s : s;
                $time['dd'] = ( today.getDate() < 10 ) ? '0' + today.getDate() : today.getDate();
                $time['mm'] = ( today.getMonth() + 1 < 10) ? '0'+ ( today.getMonth() + 1 ): today.getMonth() + 1 ;
                $time['YY'] = today.getFullYear();
                $time['Day'] = today.getDay();
                
                var monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                    "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];
                $time['Month'] = monthNames[today.getMonth()];  
                //console.log($time['Month']);
                return $time;
            };
            setInterval(function(){
                var $wrap = $('.spt-wrap', $element);
                var $current_tz = 'current_timezone';
                var $_current_time = getdate($current_tz);
                var our_clock = $_current_time[1]+":"+$_current_time[2]+":"+$_current_time[3]+" "+$_current_time[0]
                $("#spt_our_time", $element).text(our_clock);
                $('.spt-out-time', $element).attr('title','Our Time: '+$_current_time['Month']+' '+$_current_time['dd']+', '+$_current_time['YY']+' '+our_clock);
                var $timezone = '';
                var $_guest_time = getdate($timezone);
                var your_clock = $_guest_time[1]+":"+$_guest_time[2]+":"+$_guest_time[3]+" "+$_guest_time[0];
                $("#spt_local_time", $element).text(your_clock); 
                $('.spt-your-time', $element).attr('title','Your Time: '+$_guest_time['Month']+' '+$_guest_time['dd']+', '+$_guest_time['YY']+' '+your_clock);
                var days = $_current_time['YY']+'-'+$_current_time['mm']+'-'+$_current_time['dd'];
                _checkCondition($_current_time);
                                
            }, 1000);
            
            function _checkCondition($_current_time){
                var $wrap = $('.spt-wrap', $element);
                var condition = $_current_time[0] == 'AM' && $_current_time[1] >= 8 ;
                var condition1 = $_current_time[0] == 'AM' && (($_current_time[1] < 9 || $_current_time[1] >= 12) || ($_current_time[1] == 5  && $_current_time[2] <= 29)) ;
                var condition2 = $_current_time['Day'] >= 2 &&  $_current_time['Day'] <= 6; 
                if( (condition || condition1) && condition2){
                    if(!$wrap.hasClass('spt-status-on')){
                        $wrap.removeClass('spt-status-off').addClass('spt-status-on');
                    }
                }else{
                    if(!$wrap.hasClass('spt-status-off')){
                        $wrap.removeClass('spt-status-on').addClass('spt-status-off');
                    }
                }
                
                return true;
           }
            
        })('#sj_support_time_')
    });
```

```css
.sj-support-time{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap{
    background:url('../images/spt_bg.png') repeat;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-status-on{
    background-color:#EAF2DD;   
}       

.sj-support-time .spt-status-off{
    background-color: #EDF5F8;  
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-left{
    max-width:58%;
    min-width:58%;
    
    height:64px;
    float:left;
    margin:28px 10px 28px 10px;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-status-on .spt-left{
    background:url('../images/icon_on.png') no-repeat scroll transparent 10px center;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-status-off .spt-left {
    background:url('../images/icon_off.png')  no-repeat scroll transparent 10px center;
    
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-left .spt-status{
    padding-left:100px;
    color:#ABC190;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap.spt-status-off .spt-left .spt-status{
    color:#9CBAD2;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-left .spt-status > div{
    display:none;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap.spt-status-on .spt-left .spt-status .spt-online{
    display:block;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap.spt-status-off .spt-left .spt-status .spt-off{
    display:block;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-left .spt-status h3{
    margin-bottom:5px;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:0;
    height:auto;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-left .spt-status p{
    font-size:13px;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right{
    /* width:30%; */
    /* float:left; */
    margin:15px 10px 15px 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-status-on .spt-right .spt-mesg{
    background:url('../images/icon_clock_on.png') no-repeat scroll transparent 0px center;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-status-off .spt-right .spt-mesg{
    background:url('../images/icon_clock_off.png') no-repeat scroll transparent 0px center;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg  .spt-mesg-inner{
    padding-left:40px;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg  .spt-mesg-inner h5,
.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg  .spt-mesg-inner p{
    margin:0 0 5px 0;   
    color:#555555;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg  .spt-mesg-inner h5{
    font-weight:bold;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg  .spt-not-support,
.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg .spt-time{
    font-size:12px;
    color:#555555;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg .spt-time em{
    border-left:1px dotted #555555;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-left:5px;
    font-style:normal;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-mesg  .spt-not-support  em{
    color:#333;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-clock{
    margin-top:10px;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-clock .spt-time-clock{
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#333;
    border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-radius:3px;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:16px;
    padding:5px 20px;
    text-align:center;
    display:inline-block;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-clock .spt-time-clock >span{
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:13px;
}

.sj-support-time .spt-wrap .spt-right .spt-clock .spt-time-clock  + .spt-time-clock {
    margin-left:10px;
} 


.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="moduletable mod-sj-support" id="Mod385">
        <div class="module-inner">
                        
            <div class="yt-mod-mainbox">
                <div class="yt-mod-mainbox-in">
                    
<div id="sj_support_time_" class="sj-support-time">
    <div class="spt-wrap  cf spt-status-off">
        <div class="spt-left">
            <div class="spt-status ">
                <div class="spt-online">
                    <h3>We are here to serve :)</h3>
                    <p>Our support team is currently online to solve your issues.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="spt-off">
                    <h3>Our support team is currently offline</h3>
                    <p>Our support heroes might not be around this hour. Please expect some delays.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="spt-right">
            <div class="spt-mesg">
                <div class="spt-mesg-inner">
                    <h5 class="spt-text">Our support is available from</h5>
                    <p class="spt-time">Monday - Friday <em>8am - 5:30pm GMT+7</em></p>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="spt-clock cf">
                <div class="spt-time-clock spt-your-time" title="Your Time: April 03, 2021 02:24:02 AM">
                    Your time:
                    <span id="spt_local_time">02:24:02 AM</span>
                </div>
                <div class="spt-time-clock spt-out-time" title="Our Time: April 03, 2021 08:24:02 AM">
                    Our time:
                    <span id="spt_our_time">08:24:02 AM</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to mark as resolved please

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#number').keyup(function (){
        if($(this).val() == 1){
            $("#display").html("15,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 2){
            $("#display").html("28,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 3){
            $("#display").html("39,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 4){
            $("#display").html("48,000");
        }
        else if($(this).val() == 5){
            $("#display").html("55,000");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>show a text from a jquery condition</title>
</head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="text" id="number" />
<span id="display"></span>
</body>
</html>
```